# Pivot Table Option Not Getting Enabled In Excel After Protection

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, xlsxwriter

I protected the excel sheet using xlsx writer so that user can not delete, amend, or insert any rows or columns and giving few options to users like pivot table, sort, formatting. Everything is fine but pivot table option is not getting enabled on the sheet. I am sharing the dummy code below.

```py
anomalies = pd.DataFrame({'A' : np.random.randint(0, 100, 10),
                          'B' : np.random.randint(10, 100, 10),
                          'C' : np.random.randint(0, 100, 10),
                          'D' : np.random.randint(10, 100, 10)})

anomalies['Status'] = 'Pending'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('anomalies.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
anomalies.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Create some cell formats with protection properties.
locked = workbook.add_format()
locked.set_locked(True)

unlocked = workbook.add_format()
unlocked.set_locked(False)

# Format the worksheet to unlock all cells.
worksheet.set_column(anomalies.shape[1], anomalies.shape[1], None, unlocked)
worksheet.set_column(0,0, anomalies.shape[1], None, {'hidden' : 1})

worksheet.autofilter(0, 0, 0,anomalies.shape[1])  # Same as above.

# Turn worksheet protection on.
options = {
    'objects':               True,
    'scenarios':             True,
    'format_cells':          True,
    'format_columns':        True,
    'format_rows':           True,
    'insert_columns':        False,
    'insert_rows':           False,
    'insert_hyperlinks':     False,
    'delete_columns':        False,
    'delete_rows':           False,
    'select_locked_cells':   True,
    'sort':                  True,
    'autofilter':            True,
    'pivot_tables':          True,
    'select_unlocked_cells': True,
}

worksheet.protect(options = options)
workbook.close()
writer.save()
```

Comment: If not by xlsx writer is there any other workaround there, but using python?

Answer (score 0):

I ran your sample code and it enables the "Use PivotTable & Pivot Chart" protection option as expected:

[image]

However, you should note that Excel is allowing "users of this worksheet .. to use PivotTables". It doesn't say anything about allowing users to create Pivot Tables. So I assume that Excel doesn't allow creating pivot tables when options like "insert rows" are disabled. You can verify this yourself in Excel.

**Update**: It looks like Excel disables Pivot Table creation if any form of worksheet protection is turned on (even if all the options are allowed).

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? I am using Excel 2016 and on it, it's showing disabled.

Comment: The image above is from Excel 2013 but I also see the "Use PivotTable reports" enabled in Excel 2016.

Comment: So can you do the pivot? I'm not able to see the image attached by you. After running the script, the sheet I am getting is , it has Pivot Table option disabled which is under Insert tab

Comment: Yes, the Pivot Table option is disable on the insert tab. That is what I added in my update above. As I said, it looks like Excel disables Pivot Table creation if any form of worksheet protection is turned on. You can verify this yourself in Excel (without xlsxwriter).